# azure functions onedrivesdk python

Tags: python, azure, onedrive

I need to constantly poll a onedrive and when a file is dropped, I need to perform some operations on it and then re-upload it to a different folder on the same onedrive. I thought of using azure functions to download the file to a blob and then re-upload it from there. However the `onedrivesdk` (https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python) for python is not maintained anymore. Someone suggested to install the `onedrivesdk_fork` in github issues. However, that also doesn't work. How should I move forward? any alternates?

Comment: Instead of using Azure Functions and poll yourself, you can use [Access and manage files in OneDrive connector by using Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-onedrive).

Comment: @GauravMantri I need to modify the file. For e.g if it is an excel, use pandas to run a few modifications. That would be possible with logics app? I couldn't find anyway to do that?

Comment: I have not used it personally so I will be speculating but you could possibly add an action to your Logic App to move the file to Blob Storage and then process the file that way.

Comment: @GauravMantri That is what I thought to do. After downloading it to blob using azure functions, run an the modification on it..but then this sdk doesn't work.

Comment: So you don't use SDK to move the file. I think it should be possible to define an action in the Logic App to move the file to Blob Storage when the Logic App is triggered. You could have a Blob Triggered Function which will get the blob in your Function and there you update the file. I know it's a bit convoluted .